# ViewPager with Fragments is overkill?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to implement a viewPager to display an array of strings (that contains three strings). I'm trying to look up a tutorial on how I would go about something like this, but it seems that I need to use a ViewPager with fragments. Isn't there a simple was to use a ViewPager without involving fragments?

Again, I'm following the developer docs: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

But, I don't necessarily want to make the entire screen move over. I'd only like for the bottom 1/3 of my screen to swipe. Can anyone confirm that this is possible to do without fragments? Or is there another view I should use (horizontal Scroll View)

**EDIT:**

So I was doing something right. I was trying to use a ViewPager and a pagerAdapter but my application crashes. Anything glaringly broken about my code?

```
  ViewPager mPager;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_convo_detail);

            PagerAdapter mAdapter = new PagerAdapter() {

                @Override
                public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return 3;
                }
            };
            mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Have you considered just making the ViewPager only take up the bottom 1/3 of your layout?

Comment: Who said you need `Fragments` for `ViewPager` to work? Just use `ViewPager` with `PagerAdapter`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html

Comment: Yes, but I feel like it get's overly complicated with fragments, I would just like to scroll a textView (or two) in a viewpager.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `Fragment`s for `ViewPager`, Have a look : http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2012/10/viewpager-example-in-android.html

And for your second Question, this is how you take 1/3 of space:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nitpick, but that should be `60/30` or `66/33` for a third. Or just `2/1`, really.

Comment: oops let me update that.. I wanted to write 66/33. But 2/1 seems better.

Answer (score 1):

Fragments aren't that heavy, or complicated.  I don't think they are overkill for this.

However, you can use a PagerAdapter without using fragments.

A ViewPager can page plain old TextViews if that is what you want.

Basically, you don't have to use FragmentPagerAdapter.  Your PagerAdapter can take an array of Strings and return just a view for each.

Comment: Hmm... that all I really need. Two textView max. Were you able to find a tutorial on this at all? I've searched google, for specifically no fragments, but I keep getting them. I appreciate the insight.

Comment: If I'm just displaying a textView... would you recommend just using fragments, or giving it a whirl with just a PagerAdapter?

Comment: I think you should probably work through using PagerAdapter with just views.  It is good to know how to do it, and it would be less weighty than using Fragments.